# How do I end a code using Python Turtle Module when getting a Terminator Error

Tags: python, debugging, python-turtle, terminator

Hello I'm new to python and I do not really know how to fix terminator errors. I tried some other fixes I found around this website but they end up leading to other errors such as .!canvas being an invalid command name.

This is the code

```
    import turtle as turtle

    import time

    import random

    import keyboard

    delay = 0.1

    score = 0

    high_score = 0


    t=turtle

 
    t=turtle.Screen()


    t.title("Snake Xenzia [Press Esc to end game]")

    t.bgcolor("skyblue")

    t.setup(width=600, height=600)

    t.tracer(0)



    # Head of snake

    head = turtle.Turtle()

    head.shape("square")

    head.color("white")

    head.penup()

    head.goto(0, 0)

    head.direction = "Stop"



    # Food 

    food = turtle.Turtle()

    colors = random.choice(['red', 'green', 'blue'])

    shapes = random.choice(['square', 'triangle', 'circle'])

    food.speed(0)

    food.shape(shapes)

    food.color(colors)

    food.penup()

    food.goto(0, 100)



    # Adding Segments  

    pen = turtle.Turtle()

    pen.speed(0)

    pen.shape("square")

    pen.color("white")

    pen.penup()

    pen.hideturtle()

    pen.goto(0, 250)

    pen.write("Score : 0  High Score : 0", align="center",

    font=("candara", 24, "bold"))



 

    # Coding Moving

    def wkey():

        if head.direction != "down":

            head.direction = "up"



    def skey():

        if head.direction != "up":

            head.direction = "down"



    def akey():

        if head.direction != "right":

            head.direction = "left"



    def dkey():

        if head.direction != "left":

            head.direction = "right"
        

        
        



    def move():

        if head.direction == "up":

            y = head.ycor()

            head.sety(y+20)

        if head.direction == "down":

            y = head.ycor()

            head.sety(y-20)

        if head.direction == "left":

            x = head.xcor()

            head.setx(x-20)

        if head.direction == "right":

            x = head.xcor()

            head.setx(x+20)



 

         

    t.listen()

    t.onkeypress(wkey, "w")

    t.onkeypress(skey, "s")

    t.onkeypress(akey, "a")

    t.onkeypress(dkey, "d")



    segments = []



 

    # Main Gameplay

    while True:

        t.update()

        if head.xcor() > 290 or head.xcor() < -290 or head.ycor() > 290 or head.ycor() < -290:
time.sleep(1)

        head.goto(0, 0)

        head.direction = "Stop"

        colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])

        shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle'])

        for segment in segments:

            segment.goto(1000, 1000)

        segments.clear()

        score = 0

        delay = 0.1

        pen.clear()

        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(

            score, high_score), align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))

    if head.distance(food) < 20:

        x = random.randint(-270, 270)

        y = random.randint(-270, 270)

        food.goto(x, y)



        # Adding segment

        new_segment = turtle.Turtle()

        new_segment.speed(0)

        new_segment.shape("square")

        new_segment.color("orange")  # tail colour

        new_segment.penup()

        segments.append(new_segment)

        delay -= 0.001

        score += 10

        if score > high_score:

            high_score = score

        pen.clear()

        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(

            score, high_score), align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))

    # Collision

    for index in range(len(segments)-1, 0, -1):

        x = segments[index-1].xcor()

        y = segments[index-1].ycor()

        segments[index].goto(x, y)

    if len(segments) > 0:

        x = head.xcor()

        y = head.ycor()

        segments[0].goto(x, y)

    move()

           
    for segment in segments:

        if segment.distance(head) < 20:
            time.sleep(1)

            head.goto(0, 0)

            head.direction = "stop"

            colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])

            shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle'])

            for segment in segments:

                segment.goto(1000, 1000)

            segments.clear()



            score = 0

            delay = 0.1

            pen.clear()

            pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(

                score, high_score), align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))

        
    
    time.sleep(delay)


t.mainloop()
```

And this is the Terminator error received when I close the widget.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Terminator                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-9edf0a070d73> in <module>
    182 while True:
    183 
--> 184     t.update()
    185 
    186     if head.xcor() > 290 or head.xcor() < -290 or head.ycor() > 290 or head.ycor() < -290:

~\anaconda3\lib\turtle.py in update(self)
   1301         self._tracing = True
   1302         for t in self.turtles():
-> 1303             t._update_data()
   1304             t._drawturtle()
   1305         self._tracing = tracing

~\anaconda3\lib\turtle.py in _update_data(self)
   2644 
   2645     def _update_data(self):
-> 2646         self.screen._incrementudc()
   2647         if self.screen._updatecounter != 0:
   2648             return

~\anaconda3\lib\turtle.py in _incrementudc(self)
   1290         if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
   1291             TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
-> 1292             raise Terminator
   1293         if self._tracing > 0:
   1294             self._updatecounter += 1

Terminator:
```

Comment: Same question as [How can we get a work around for the Python raise Terminator error for the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72910438/how-can-we-get-a-work-around-for-the-python-raise-terminator-error-for-the-scree). Please only ask a question once, and use one account (unless there's some coincidence here, or you're two separate people working on the same project)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we get a work around for the Python raise Terminator error for the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72910438/how-can-we-get-a-work-around-for-the-python-raise-terminator-error-for-the-scree)